# calculating position with the LinearAcceleration

Tags: android, accelerometer, linear-algebra, android-sensors, sensor-fusion

I am trying to calculate a new X position based on Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION that i will be applying to my android game.

I an starting with the following variables all set to 0:

```
float newX=0;
float lastX0 =0;
float lastX1 =0;
```

and my Time Variables set initially like so:

```
float newTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
float lastTime0 = lastTime1 = newTime;
```

Then my On SensorChange looks like this:

```
public onSensorChanged(SensorEvent evt){
if (type == Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION) {

                    newTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
                    float oldDeltaTime = lastTime1-lastTime0;
                    float newDeltaTime = newTime- lastTime1;
                   if(oldDeltaTime<1)oldDeltaTime =1;

                    newX = lastX1 + ((lastX1 - lastX0)/oldDeltaTime)*newDeltaTime +(evt.values[0]/2)*(newDeltaTime*newDeltaTime);
                    lastX0 = lastX1;
                    lastX1 = newX;
                    lastTime0 = lastTime1;
                    lastTime1 = newTime;

                    Log.v("SENSOR MAN LINEAR", "new X:"+newX);


                }
}
```

but i am getting 0 all the time for newX in my log.

Has anyone successfully translated LinearAcceleration into position?
can anyone figure out what i am doing wrong..

i am crying inside!

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that the errors associated with measuring `Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` make it impossible to get a good estimate of position from `Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` alone.

I'm not sure why you're getting zero all the time.  To debug that, I'd simply `Log.v` all your variables to work out what the problem is.

I'm also not sure that your formula for `newX` is making the best use of the sensor values.  Acceleration is a change of speed, and you implementation doesn't seem to correspond to that.

Finally, the event values depend on the orientation of the device.  So to have any chance of success, you need to combine with compass sensor readings to try and work out how the `Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` values map to directions in the real world.

Comment: well in my sensor manager i am also getting creating a rotaionMatrix of the device orientation using both the accelerometer and compass fused together..  would you be so kind as to show how you would write this, i also have a lat and lon as well for the current device gps location

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.  My latest idea on this is to try using a Kalman filter, because Kalman filters are good at dealing with estimates that have error bars associated with them.  I was asking some questions about using Kalman filters for position and velocity (here)[http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8860/more-on-kalman-filter-for-position-and-velocity]. One could also extend to have position+velocity+acceleration state vectors in the Kalman filter.  In any case, this is a highly non-trivial problem, and at present I don't know of any satisfactory solutions.